# Word 2013 switching to "All Markup"

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office-2013

Word 2013 has a great feature for reviewing and editing documents. Rather than having to see every edit that was made to a document, you can enable viewing "Simple Markup," which simply shows a line in the margin indicating a change has been made.

Unfortunately, this new option seems to be slippery. When I set it to Simple Markup while working on a document, every few minutes and for no apparent reason it will switch on its own to "All Markup." It seems to occur only when the document is out of focus, meaning I'm working in another window.

How can I get Word 2013 to keep my selection for markup viewing?

Comment: Word will switch to all markup if you click the line in the margin or any other markup element. Are you sure you aren't clicking one of these by a mistake when you switch back to your document?

Comment: This happens even if I don't click on the file at all. I've watched it with the file in the background and another window in focus and it happens without switching back at all.

Comment: Have you tried on a different machine? Does the same thing happen? (I would also try if I had Word 2013 installed but I don't). If so, it might well be a bug in Word.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? It's really getting on my nerves!

Comment: @Zevran I didn't find a very satisfying answer, but I've just posted my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probably was apparently caused by the Endnote addon I had installed. After disabling that addon, things returned to normal. Occasionally some action, such as adding a citation with Zotero, will still switch it back to "All Markup," but it doesn't happen for no reason anymore.

2015-11-06 UPDATE: It appears that Zotero now switches things to "No Markup" instead of the "All Markup" that it used to do.

Comment: Right, yeah I'm using endnote too. This is going to make thesis writing very annoying... well done on tracking down the problem! Maybe I'll just stick to vim and latex :P

Comment: @Zevran Vim and LaTeX are a great way to go. Zotero is a free replacement for Endnote that, at least so far, has not caused the random switching for me.